# ExtJS: cannot call method 'getProxy'

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Why does this fail with `cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined`?

```
{
    name: 'customer_name',
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Customer',
    emptyText: 'ex. Google',
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        storeId: 'myStore',
        fields: ['name'],
        data: [ 'google', 'facebook', 'twitter']
    }),
    displayField: 'name'
}
```

taken from [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore)...

It 100% fails at this peice of code.

Comment: Did you get other errors in the console? Syntax error as plee mentioned? Or is that a typo in the question?

Comment: Ya that's just a type form copying over

Comment: Everything is working fine, your error must be somewhere else https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fb

Comment: @JuanMendes I comment out the `store`, `queryMode`, `displayField` .. and it works. I comment in.. it breaks.

Comment: We just proved to you that the code you posted works, you need to start from that, not by still saying it doesn't work. Go to the fiddle I posted and see what's different from what you have

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm using MVC if it makes a difference. I.e. I'm defining this inside an `items: []` of a view I'm `Ext.define()`'ing

Comment: Show all your relevant code, create a fiddle that breaks that others can look at. Refining your question will make it more likely that other will be able to help, unfortunately, I can't keep trying to guess what's going on

Comment: Try `store: {
                type: 'array',
                storeId: 'myStore',
                fields: ['name'],
                data: ['google', 'facebook', 'twitter']
            }`, it could be related to dynamic loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're defining items on the prototype of your object. You shouldn't do that because it means it will be shared by all instances, also it will try to instantiate your store while defining the class, instead of when the class is instantiated.

Instead of

```
Ext.define('my.Panel', {
    items: {
        name: 'customer_name',
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Customer',
        emptyText: 'ex. Google',
        allowBlank: false,
        queryMode: 'local',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            storeId: 'myStore',
            fields: ['name'],
            data: [ 'google', 'facebook', 'twitter']
        }),
        displayField: 'name'
    } 
});
```

Do

```
Ext.define('my.Panel', {
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items =  {
            name: 'customer_name',
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Customer',
            emptyText: 'ex. Google',
            allowBlank: false,
            queryMode: 'local',
            store: {
                // Let Ext instantiate the store
                type: 'array',
                // Don't use this, it's an euphemism for a global
                storeId: 'myStore',
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [ 'google', 'facebook', 'twitter']
            },
        displayField: 'name'
    } 
});
```

Comment: lol I was just amidst a massive fiddle. Yes, this does fix the problem - I'm very appreciative of your help. That being said, I do stuff like `Ext.create('someView')` inside handler functions for events in my controllers without any problem..

Comment: @ColinMartell When you create stuff from your controllers, the app is already loaded, so `Ext.create` is fine there.  The problem is that you were creating the store while the class was being defined.

Comment: Ah perfect! Ya I was going to upvote & mark correct; just wanted to know *why* this worked somewhat first ;) Thanks a ton man

Comment: Note that you can use `Ext.create` if you call it from `initComponent`, I just used the literal to show off :). The literal should even work from the prototype, but could break if you had more than one instance and the store could be modified

Answer (score 1):

I think cause it is missing an end quote in `'name`

This code works fine

```
Ext.widget({
    name: 'customer_name',
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Customer',
    emptyText: 'ex. Google',
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        storeId: 'myStore',
        fields: ['name'],
        data: [ 'google', 'facebook', 'twitter']
    }),
    displayField: 'name'
})
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a `Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got function constructor()` error..